# Mailcore2 Render HTML Body

Tags: ios, mailcore2

I don't understand how to render the email body.

The wiki use a deprecate method, so this is not an option. And then I started to use

```
[message htmlRenderingWithFolder:@"INBOX" delegate:self]
```

so I don't understand exactly what I need to execute to load the HTML.

BTW the example app it's not clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe what you tried and what results you got? and what was unclear to you? Could you point out in the wiki what's deprecated? For now, I can't tell you more than "have a look at the example app".

Comment: Thanks @DinhViêtHoà the problem was the idle operation was running... I tried with the example app but it's not nice the code... If I find time i will make a better example. Thanks for your help